# Cordova WKWebView IOS no asp.net session cookie

Tags: ios, asp.net, cordova, cookies

Hi im building a app with Cordova, im using the wkwebview to show de app at an ios device, the big problem I have is that i'm using Session.SessionId on asp.net to see if mi client is conected and do the respectives request to the api. For the request im using ajax. but the browser is not storeing the cookie. I been searching for the solution at google and stack but no luck at all.

I know that if i use wkwebview i have to do crossdomain and the ajax will not get the header or cookie of the response. so im sending the sessionId like a var but i cant build up a cookie and I cant use cookieless at mi server.

If some one have any solution for this it will be greate im only developing with js. and asp.net for the api.

Comment: I would suggest a different approach - use _tokens_ instead. You will have to manage obtaining and sending in each Ajax request. On the server, you verify token (validity, expiration, etc). Hth.

Comment: sorry for the delay i did use the token to solve the problem thanks for the answer. I`m working with a .net nuget that do all the stuff for me.